# ¿Por qué hay que usar este rango en el bucle for?

Tags: python

Este problema casi lo logro solucionar pero me falto el -2 en el loop, despues de ver la solución aun no entiendo por que hay que poner ese -2 en `for i in range(len(str)-2):`

El problema es: Devolver True si el numero de veces que aparece la palabra "dog" es igual al numero de veces que aparece la palabra "cat"
Esta es la solucion:

```
def cat_dog(str):
  count_dog = 0
  count_cat = 0

  for i in range(len(str)-2):
    if str[i:i+3] == "dog":
      count_dog += 1
    if str[i:i+3] == "cat":
      count_cat += 1
  
  return count_dog == count_cat
```

Comment: Revisa el título de la pregunta. No te estás refiriendo en ella a ningún condicional, sino al rango del `for`. Puedes titularla ¿Por qué hay que usar este rango en el bucle for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay que poner ese menos dos, porque al validar la palabra, vos estas mirando las dos letras siguientes, y en el caso de que no realices el recorrido hasta `len(str)-2`, cuando te pases vas a tener un error por indice fuera del rango, ejemplo con string **"dogcat"**:

1. **dog** cat
2. d **ogc** at
3. do **gca** t
4. dog **cat**
5. dogc **at'error index out of range'**